# Prove a biconditional statement with limsup.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I'm really stuck with my homework in mathematical analysis. I would be very glad, if you could give me some ideas/solutions or tips, how to get this done. The task is as follows:

Let $(x_{n})$ be a bounded sequence and let M $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Prove, that

$\limsup\limits_{ n\to\infty} x_{n} $ $\leq$ M
if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0 $, there exists an N $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ so, that
$x_{n} < M + \varepsilon$ for every $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

To give you some frame I will solve one side, and will leave the other side to you.

---

Denote: $$s_k:=\sup\{x_n\mid n\geq k\}$$ Then $(s_k)$ is a decreasing sequence, and by definition: $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k\tag1$$

If $x_n<M+\epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$ then $M+\epsilon$ is an upper bound for the set $\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}$. Consequently the least upper bound of this set will not exceed $M+\epsilon$:$$s_N\leq M+\epsilon$$
Since $(s_k)$ is decreasing we have:$$k\geq N\implies s_k\leq M+\epsilon$$ so that: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k\leq M+\epsilon$$

This for every $\epsilon>0$ so finally, and applying $(1)$ we find:$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k\leq M$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!  Now, based on your solution, I think (not 100% sure tho), that i might have got the other side done.

Comment: The picture of my solution is here: https://imgur.com/a/7twIv. Am I doing it right? :)

Comment: Yes, that looks good.